# Rsync from python can't find path

Tags: python, subprocess, rsync

I've tried to run rsync from python via Popen and via subprocess.check_call, getting the very same error:

```
subprocess.check_call(['rsync', '-au', '/opt/catflow/EpressCatalog/*', '/Users/pistacchio/dev/epress/catflow/portal/branches/noscript/frontend/static/repo/usr/2/catalogs/2/builds/ipad'])
rsync: link_stat "/opt/catflow/EpressCatalog/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
*** CalledProcessError: Command '['rsync', '-au', '/opt/catflow/EpressCatalog/*', '/Users/pistacchio/dev/epress/catflow/portal/branches/noscript/frontend/static/repo/usr/2/catalogs/2/builds/ipad']' returned non-zero exit status 23
```

Seems like the problem is that it can't find (or access) `/opt/catflow/EpressCatalog/*`. Not only it exists, but running it from the command line gives a correct result.

Any help?

Comment: the subprocess module sometimes does weird things to parameters. Try adding 'echo' to the first of the list and see what command it actually is running. The * may be causing problems.

Comment: the `*` is function of the shell. set `shell=True` and try again

Comment: echo gives what expected, i think: rsync -au frontend/static/skeletons/EpressCatalog/* /Users/pistacchio/dev/epress/catflow/portal/branches/noscript/frontend/static/repo/usr/2/catalogs/2/builds/ipad

removing the "*", thought, seemed to solve the problem. if you write this as answer i'll mark it as accepted. also, why does the '*' cause problems? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module handle the quoting of arguments by itself.
When there are whitespaces in one argument entry than it is quoted by default.

Simplified [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen):

```
['-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt']
```

Is called on the shell as

```
-input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt"
```

**Security note**:
Do never use `shell=True`. It opens the risk for shell injection attacks. See the [official docu](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#security-considerations) for more details.